# Xero Developer Account

Tags: xero-api

I have a confusion about xero developer account. When signing up for developer account, xero says 30 day free trial and max 25 organization's(uncertified) connection, while some people says that it is completely free. Can someone with exact information guide me about developer account if it can be used for unlimited period of time or do I have to pay for a developer account also. and also guide me about how I can upgrade from 25 connections to unlimited connections.

Tried to ask question about xero developer account and hope to get exact answer.

Comment: Based on the company's web-site, it's a 30 day free trial for developers, and then it's charged by the month. I don't know about the quantity of organization connections - it's a question for Xero themselves. Some of Xero's facilities are free to use by partners, which may be where you're getting the 'free' from.

Comment: So if i have a paid xero accounting account already and i register the same account for developer then it will be free?? because i already paid to xero for same email.

Comment: According [to the documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/development-accounts/) your paid organization subscription also covers developer integration. The documentation indicates that you need to become an app partner to get unlimited connections. There's a [pretty legible blog post](https://www.codat.io/blog/5-things-you-need-to-know-before-you-integrate-with-the-xero-api/) describing it.

Comment: I've had a developer account for several years and not paid anything. The test organisations that I use to test my software expire after 30 days (presumably not if I pay) so I have to create a new one after the last one expired.